# How do I get rss feed xml schema back from twitter api in Classic ASP into an local file

Tags: xml, asp-classic, rss, httpwebrequest

Here is my asp file calling the url:

```
<%
Response.Expires = -1

URLToRSS = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=nrcGOV"

Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.setProxy 2, "www.proxy.nrc.gov:80"
xmlHttp.Open "GET", URLToRSS, false
xmlHttp.Send()
RSSXML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

response.Write(RSSXML)

%>
```

I want this to basically regurgitate the xml schema that is located at the url into the file on my local server. Whenever I run it all I get back is a question mark in the browser window with no errors in the window, runtime or in the console. I tried outputting the RSSXML with asp like so:

```
<%

URLToRSS = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=nrcGOV"

Set xmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
xmlHttp.setProxy 2, "www.proxy.nrc.gov:80"
xmlHttp.Open "GET", URLToRSS, false
xmlHttp.Send()
RSSXML = xmlHttp.ResponseText

Set xmlDOM = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmlDOM.async = False
xmlDOM.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
xmlDOM.Load(RSSXML)

Set itemList = XMLDom.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")

For Each itemAttrib In itemList
   newsSubject =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("title").text
   newsExtract =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("description").text
   newsDate =itemAttrib.SelectSingleNode("pubDate").text
   %>
   <div>
      <div><%=newsSubject%></div>
      <div><%=newsDate%></div>
      <div><%=newsExtract%></div>
   </div>
<%
Next

Set xmlDOM = Nothing
Set itemList = Nothing

%>
```

I di get an error once saying something about an invalid character in the context once but that disappeared. The XML displays fine in my browser windows and I checked to make sure all versions of xml were running on theserver as well as sent the request out through proxy. I am out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: have you tried `RSSXML = xmlHttp.ResponseXML.xml` instead of `RSSXML = xmlHttp.ResponseText`

Comment: yes, they both write nothing

Comment: @DJERock did you ever make any progress with this?